# How to translate questions beginning with "Is it"

Tags: verbes, questions, inversion

I struggle to translate questions which begin with "Is it", "Is that", "Is this" and "Are those". Consider the following examples:

a) "What is your ethnicity? Is it French or Italian?"

I would translate it as « Quelle est ton ethnicité? **Est-ce** le français ou le italien ?»

b) "I like your shoes. Are they cheap or expensive?

I would translate it as « J'aime tes chaussures. **Sont-ce** bon marché ou cher ?»

Are my translations correct? My aim was to ask these questions in a formal manner. Was I correct to invert **C'est** and **Ce sont**?

How does one ask questions beginning with "Is it", "Is that", "Is this" and "Are those" formally and informally?

Comment: We'd rather say *ethnie* than *ethnicité* in French but in any case, these words are controversial and too technical to be used like this. An idiomatic conversation would be *Tu es de quelle origine ? Française ou italienne ?*

Comment: @jlliagre Thank you for the heads up but how would I ask the question formally? Also, my real question still stands. How do I ask questions beginning with "Is it", "Is that", "Is this", and "Are those"?

Comment: Formal French might be *De quelle origine es-tu / êtes-vous ? Française ou italienne ?*

Comment: Note that if you were really being formal, you wouldn't ask the question at all. What could possibly justify wanting to know something so personal in a formal situation?

Comment: I just want to say that some of these forms are **too** formal (at least for spoken language). Even if you're very polite, talking to your boss or the president. I've never used "*sont-ce*" unironically, and I've never seen anyone using it not to make a joke or an impression. It's something you can hear from parodies of aristocrats, or ancient times conversations, but clearly not day-to-day stuff. (That includes almost all inversions with "je", like "Qu'ouïs-je" or "Pensé-je")

Answer (score 1):

a)  Quelle est ton ethnicité? Est-ce le groupe ethnique des français ou des italien ?

b)  J'aime tes chaussures. Sont-elles bon marché ou chères ?

The principle of inversion does apply in this context of question, however, the plural "sont-ce" is not much used; speakers and writers will rather use a personal pronoun; moreover, the affirmative form corresponding to "Sont-ce bon marché ou cher ?" does not exist; you dont say "Ce sont bon marché ou chères.". You have to say "Ce sont **des chaussures** bon marché ou chères."; then the question form becomes "Sont-ce des chaussures bon marché ou chères ?"; finally, as you probably noticed, there a necessary agreement of the adjective (gender and number: chères).

Here is the informal way to say that;

- Ce sont des chaussures bon marché ou chères ?
- (*more informal yet*) C'est des chaussures bon marché ou chères ?

**is it  => est-ce que c'est**

- (*standard*) Est-ce que c'est bon ? => Is it good?_ (*informal*) C'est bon ?
- (*standard*) Est-ce que c'est un nuage ? => Is it a cloud? _ (*informa*) C'est un nuage

**is this => Est-ce que ceci est**

- (*standard*) Est-ce que ceci est assez chaud ? => Is this warm enough? (*informal*) C'est assez chaud ça ?

**is that => Est-ce que cela est**

- (*standard*) Est-ce que cela est un sac ? =>  Is that a bag ? _ (*informal*) C'est un sac ça ?

**are those => est-ce que ceux-là sont**

- (*standard*) Est-ce que ceux-là sont à vendre ? => Are those for sale? (*informal*) Ils sont à vendre ceux-là ? *or* Ceux-là sont à vendre ?

Comment: What you describe as formal is standard French. Formal French would be: *Ces chaussures, sont-elles bon marché ou chères ?*, *Est-ce bon ?*, *Est-ce un nuage ?*, *Est-ce assez chaud ?*, *Est-ce un sac ?*, *Ceux-là sont-ils à vendre ?*

Comment: Also, it's downright weird to mention "bon marché ou chères" in the same sentence, they're mutually exclusive so just as about one.

Comment: @GeorgeM Dans ce magasin les chaussures sont bon marché ou chères ; tout est une question de qualité, et nous avons des articles pour des petites bourses tout aussi bien que des articles pour la clientèle argentée.

Comment: @LPH Merci beaucoup pour votre aide! :) I do have a quick question: Consider the sentence « Elles sont des chaussures bon marché ou chères. » What is the grammar rule that causes the word « des chaussures » to be inserted after 'Ce sont' causing the sentence to become « Ce sont des chaussures bon marché ou chères. »?

Comment: @CubbyKushi I can't refer to any given rule ; I can however relate this form to what seems to me a very similar form in English and that you'll recognize certainly : "Those are expensive shoes.". Except for the adj/noun inversion and the article ("des", it helps to be conscious ot the fact that English has a zero indefinite plural article, but not French) the construction is the same; you can say also "Those are expensive." and everyone understands that you're talking about the shoes; but then you can also insert "shoes" and "those" still stands for "shoes". (continued next)

Comment: @CubbyKushi A general principle, but which is no great explainer of anything is that in the construction "subject-predicate", in the predicate, besides the copula (or linking verb) you can have either a predicate adjective (expensive) or a predicate nominal (expensive shoes). It 's just the way things are in grammar and it's equally true for both languages. The question is "why when "ce" is used is it necessary  to insert a noun?"; I think it's a matter of gender; the gender of "ce" is neutral whereas the gender of "celles-ci" is feminin; (continued next)

Comment: @CubbyKushi  so you can say "Celles-ci sont chères." or "Celles-ci sont des chaussures chères."; notice that you can say "Ce me semble être cher." but not "Ce me semble être chère." (It makes no sense).